# No puedo eliminar el espacio o juntar el texto con la imagen en HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy recien empezando con el HTML y el CSS y tengo un problema, estoy haciendo una pagina proyecto y estoy en la parte del header, todo me fue bien con el nav y eso pero cuando quiero juntar el texto del logo con la imagen del logo queda un espacio enorme entre estos. Me gustaria poner o el texto debajo de la imagen del logo, o al lado pegado, con la palabra ''Onigiri'' arriba y abajo de esa la palabra ''Sushi'', digamos, ambas palabras una encima de otra.
Si alguien puede ayudarme con esto porfavor lo agradeceria bastante, desde ya gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Onigiri Sushi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<header class="header">
    <div class="container logo-nav-container">
    <img class="logo" src="onigiri.png" alt="" width="120px" height="120px">
    <h1>Onigiri Sushi</h1>
        <nav class="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Koulen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</header>

<main class="main">

    <div class="class container">

        <h1>
            Hola soy el título
        </h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates illum eius, temporibus architecto molestiae, ducimus aut facilis, nesciunt dignissimos libero eos? Soluta facere vero, qui molestiae facilis magni cum et?</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, cum dolor consequuntur quos, repellat impedit culpa tempora fuga voluptatem eaque, accusamus ratione quaerat a excepturi autem hic provident amet dolorum?</p>

    </div>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Página diseñada por Santino Fernandez</p>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Y mi código CSS:

```
body {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
   color: #333;
   font-size: 1.2rem;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   margin: 0%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

p{
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
}

.container {
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 0rem 0;
    font-family: 'Koulen', cursive;

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-nav-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

.main {
    padding-top: 12rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es meter el logo y el texto dentro de un div y jugar con eso:

```
<header class="header">
<div class="container logo-nav-container">
    <div class="logoimagen">
        <img class="logo" src="onigiri.png" alt="" width="120px" height="120px">
        <h1>Onigiri Sushi</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Ya dentro de ese div puede jugar con el width, con display...

```
 .logoimagen {
     display: flex;
     width: 100px:
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad!

Answer (score 0):

A lo que te ha dicho @PedroPicateclas le completaría con

```
.logoimagen {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
}
```

y así te aseguras que siempre van a estar el logo arriba y el texto abajo.

Y si quieres que se ponga uno al lado del otro pues con

```
.logoimagen {
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!